# What's the difference between "2*2" and "2**2" in Python?

Tags: python, syntax

What is the difference between the following statements?

Statement 1:

```
var=2**2*3
```

Statement 2:

```
var2=2*2*3
```

I see no difference.
This raises the following question.

Why is Statement 1 used if we can use Statement 2?

Comment: When you make tests with numbers follow these 2 rules: only use prime numbers (you were ok) and never use 2 twice.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Try:

```
2**3*2
```

and

```
2*3*2
```

to see the difference.

`**` is the operator for "power of". In your particular operation, 2 to the power of 2 yields the same as 2 times 2.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator and http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations are important @Masi, consider reading them.

Comment: Just tried `**` with `mmap()`. Thought it had similar semantics to `//`. I was terribly wrong. I've never seen a computer so mad at me.

Comment: Which one is more efficient, do you know? 10**2 or 10*10?

Answer (score 34):

Double stars (`**`) are exponentiation.  So "2 times 2" and "2 to the power 2" are the same.  Change the numbers and you'll see a difference.

Comment: In fact, the double stars are pretty commonly used in any language where the carat (^) is reserved for bitwise XOR operations.  I don't think I've seen double stars with any other meaning than exponentiation.

Comment: They were used in FORTRAN a long, long time ago.

Comment: Double star was introduced as power in Fortran which doesn't have bitwise operator symbols.

Comment: Curious fact: Google uses both  ^ and **

Comment: @Martin: Fortran also predates ASCII, so it couldn't depend on the `^` character being available.

Answer (score 14):

```
  2**2 means 2 squared (2^2)
  2*2 mean 2 times 2 (2x2)
```

In this case they happen to have the same value, but...

```
  3**3*4 != 3*3*4
```

Answer (score 9):

For visual learners.........................

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To specifically answer your question **Why is the code1 used if we can use code2?** I might suggest that the programmer was thinking in a mathematically broader sense. Specifically, perhaps the broader equation is a power equation, and the fact that both first numbers are "2" is more coincidence than mathematical reality. I'd want to make sure that the broader context of the code supports it being

```
var = x * x * y
```

in all cases, rather than in this specific case alone. This could get you in big trouble if x is anything but 2.

Answer (score 2):

2**2 = 2 power-of 2

2*2 = 2 times 2

Answer (score 2):

The `**` operator in Python is really "power;" that is, `2**3 = 8`.

Answer (score 1):

The top one is a "power" operator, so in this case it is the same as 2 * 2 equal to is 2 to the power of 2. If you put a 3 in the middle position, you will see a difference.

Answer (score 1):

A double asterisk means to the power of. A single asterisk means multiplied by. 2<sup>2</sup> is the same as 2x2 which is why both answers came out as 4.

Answer (score 1):

Power has more precedence than multiply, so:

```
2**2*3 = (2^2)*3
2*2*3 = 2*2*3
```