# Double Asterisk

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and really stumped on this. I'm reading from a book and the code works fine; I just don't get it!

```
T[i+1] = m*v[i+1]ˆ**/L
```

What's with the double asterisk part of this code? It's even followed by a forward slash. The variable L is initialized with the value 1.0 However, it looks like someone slumped over the keyboard, but the code works fine. Is this a math expression or something more? I would appreciate the help understanding this. Thanks!

full code:

```
from pylab import *
g = 9.8 # m/sˆ2
dt = 0.01 # s
time = 10.0 # s
v0 = 2.0 # s
D = 0.05 #
L = 1.0 # m
m = 0.5 # kg
# Numerical initialization
n = int(round(time/dt))
t = zeros(n,float)
s = zeros(n,float)
v = zeros(n,float)
T = zeros(n,float)
# Initial conditions
v[0] = v0
s[0] = 0.0
# Simulation loop
i = 0
while (i<n AND T[i]>=0.0):
    t[i+1] = t[i] + dt
    a = -D/m*v[i]*abs(v[i])-g*sin(s[i]/L)
    v[i+1] = v[i] + a*dt
    s[i+1] = s[i] + v[i+1]*dt
    T[i+1] = m*v[i+1]ˆ**/L + m*g*cos(s[i+1]/L)
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: Looks like it's unpacking

Comment: What data types are `m` and `v[i + 1]`?

Comment: `**` is either exponentiation or keyword argument expansion anywhere I've seen it.  what is `v`, what is `L`, what book?

Comment: that syntax is not valid

Comment: I've added the whole code - the syntax is not valid? it compiles and runs fine.

Comment: I think, another interesting thing would be the meaning of the combination of `^`and `**`

Comment: Yes, I thought ** would be an exponent, is this only a math operation or something more? Thanks for the help ! This is really strange syntax

Comment: That's not a caret, it's Unicode character `\u02c6` [(MODIFIER LETTER CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2c6/index.htm).

Comment: The caret (`^`) does a [bitwise XOR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451386/what-does-the-caret-operator-in-python-do). But this syntax is not valid.

Comment: Are you sure it compiles in Python? What is the `AND` in `i<n AND T[i]>=0.0`?

Comment: `**` is the exponential operator in python, but `ˆ**` should not compile

Comment: According to the book Elementary Mechanics Using Python the formula is: `m*(v^2)/L`, so it must be `m*(v[i+1]**2)/L`.

Comment: This definitely doesn't look like standard Python. What book are you using? And can you provide a screenshot of your IDE and/or command line?

Answer (score 11):

This code is from the book "Elementary Mechanics Using Python: A Modern Course Combining Analytical and Numerical Techniques".
According to the formula on the page 255:
[image]

So the Python line should be:

```
T[i+1] = m*v[i+1]**2/L + m*g*cos(s[i+1]/L)
```

Comment: I got it wrong. Thanks for the correction and noticing the math formula. It seems to have run ok with IronPython 2.7 in Visual Studio with my set-up. This works as expected, Thanks Delimitry

Comment: Then you need to stop using IronPython 2.7 and/pr Visual Studio.  It accepts nonsense syntax!

Answer (score 8):

> What's with the double asterisk part of this code?

The answer to your core questions (at least as it exists of this writing) is the double asterisk (star) is power -- "raise to the power". So, `i**3`  would be "cube `i`".

My (cross check) source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1044866/18196